# Get td title nodeJS

Tags: html, node.js

I try to get title of this html code

```
<td id="ct4"><div class="ltr inline" title="153,903,173">153.903 M</div></td>
```

with this nodeJS code

```
let buyVolume = document.getElementById('ct4').title;
```

but it returns null any idea?

Comment: The `td` has no title, the `div` inside it has.

Comment: let buyVolume = document.getElementById('ct4').div.title ?

Comment: Change `document.getElementById('ct4').title` to `document.querySelector('#ct4 div').title`

Comment: Thanks thats work :)